# Can Clang use LLVM TableGen produced headers?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I'm working on Clang fork for AVR:
https://github.com/4ntoine/clang/tree/avr-support

AVR Subtargets are described in LLVM backend fork for AVR [AVR.td](https://github.com/dylanmckay/avr-llvm/blob/avr-support/lib/Target/AVR/AVR.td) and LLVM TableGen generates [AVRSubtarget.h](https://github.com/dylanmckay/avr-llvm/blob/avr-support/lib/Target/AVR/AVRSubtarget.h) in `lib/Target/AVR/`

I'de like to use `AVRSubTypeKV` in `AVRTargetInfo.hasFeature()` in [Targets.cpp](https://github.com/4ntoine/clang/blob/avr-support/lib/Basic/Targets.cpp) from generated `AVRGenSubtargetInfo.inc` to check if the feature is supported by CPU (MCU):

```
// Sorted (by key) array of values for CPU subtype.
extern const llvm::SubtargetFeatureKV AVRSubTypeKV[] = {
  { "at43usb320", "Select the at43usb320 processor", AVR::FeatureAVR31, 0ULL },
  { "at43usb355", "Select the at43usb355 processor", AVR::FeatureAVR3, 0ULL },
  { "at76c711", "Select the at76c711 processor", AVR::FeatureAVR3, 0ULL },
  { "at86rf401", "Select the at86rf401 processor", AVR::FeatureRF401, 0ULL },
  { "at90c8534", "Select the at90c8534 processor", AVR::FeatureAVR2, 0ULL },
  { "at90can128", "Select the at90can128 processor", AVR::FeatureAVR51, 0ULL },
  { "at90can32", "Select the at90can32 processor", AVR::FeatureAVR5, 0ULL },
  ...
```

I've tried to `#include <AVRSubtarget.h>` from [LLVM](https://github.com/dylanmckay/avr-llvm/blob/avr-support/lib/Target/AVR/AVRSubtarget.h) in [Targets.cpp](https://github.com/4ntoine/clang/blob/avr-support/lib/Basic/Targets.cpp) but it can't be found.

So how can i use LLVM TableGen produced files in Clang?

Answer (score 0):

The LLVM build structure demands header files in `include/llvm/Target` and then you can include the generated header with `#include "llvm/Target/AVRSubtarget.h"`. The best example how llvm-tblgen files could be used inside of clang is the `Intrinsics.h` header in `include/llvm/IR/`.

Comment: i'm not sure Transforms is correct directory for it as related to Targets and not Transforms.

Comment: @4ntoine sorry I was in a hurry when I wrote the answer. You are absolutly right. The headers should be in a subdirectory related to their usage. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the backend tablegen generated headers in this way. Take a look at how the other targets in clang (Targets.cpp and other files like this) abstract out the header/intrinisic usage.

The rationale behind this is so that aspects of the front end can be used without including the backend. (OK, this falls down a bit since we use the backend for parsing MS style inline assembly, but work with me here)

Also, there's no specific way to pass subtarget specific values down to the creation of the TargetMachine. You'll want to pass in the target, cpu, and feature string where the TargetMachine is created and that'll initialize the backend fully. Specific front end options can be used to turn on various features that will get turned on.

Comment: I tend to think this answer is correct. I was unable to find any target which uses backend tablegen results for features. The only reason i'd like to do it it's because there are lot's of features-mcus relations and i did not understand why not to do it originally. In suggested approach i have to describe that relations programmatically in `hasFeature()`.

Comment: How are you planning on enabling the features from the front end? I.e. if you were going to enable them from the command line then you'd need to add the command line option support anyhow. At that point enabling the element of the feature string is pretty small. See how most of the other targets handle -march etc.